# jQuery Image Viewport Calculation Algorithm to Avoid Scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating an image hover effect but I am having problem with it. When I hover over certain images, the **scrollbars** appear which I want to avoid but don't know how to do so. I believe it has to do with viewport and calculations but am not sure how that is done.

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/upuref/1)**

**[JSBin Code](http://jsbin.com/upuref/1/edit)**

Here is the code:

```
$('.simplehover').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);        
    var isrc = $this[0].src, dv = null;
                        
    $this.mouseenter(function(e){
        dv = $('<div />')
            .attr('class', '__shidivbox__')
            .css({
                display: 'none',
                zIndex : 9999,
                position: 'absolute',
                top: e.pageY + 20,
                left: e.pageX + 20
            })
            .html('<img alt="" src="' + isrc + '" />')
            .appendTo(document.body);           
        dv.fadeIn('fast');
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
        dv.fadeOut('fast');
    });         

});
```

Can anyone please help me how do I make it so that hovered image appears at such place that scrollbars dont appear? (Of course we can't avoid scrollbar if image size is very very big)

I just want to show original image on zoom while avoiding scrollbars as much as possible.

**Please note** that I am planning to convert it into jQuery plugin and therefore I can't force users of plugin to have `overflow` set to `hidden`. The solution has do with **viewport**, **left**, **top**, **scroll width** and **height**, **window width/height** properties that I can incorporate into plugin later on.

---

## Update:

I have come up with this:

http://jsbin.com/upuref/14

However, it is very very hacky and not 100% perfect. I am looking for a better algorithim/solution. I have seen many hover plugins that do this very nicely but since I am not that good at this, I can't do it perfectly well. For example [**Hover Zoom Chrome Plugin**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nonjdcjchghhkdoolnlbekcfllmednbl) does great job of showing hovered images at appropriate place based on their size.

Comment: What do you mean by scrollbars? Do you mean the window's scrollbars? I'm not getting any scrollbars in your example.

Comment: @TimLamballais You might not get scrolls if you are viewing in really high resolution where the image doesn't go outside the viewport.

Comment: You can hide the scroll bars.. but that would not be the desired output. How do you want the it to be.. if the image is really big?

Comment: Personally, I'd check the viewport width and change the size of the larger images based on that value. If someone has a narrow screen (e.g. netbook, widescreen monitor in portrait mode, etc.) the images may go off the side of the page no matter how you position them. You may want to make them appear between the rows of thumbnails (or before them) instead... or use a lightbox approach.

Comment: Here is one solution: http://jsbin.com/upuref/4 However it is hacky not 100% perfect. A better calculation algo is needed.

Comment: @TimLamballais: The scrollbars show up when hovering over an image for example big image. I have updated the question with more info and my attempt which isn't perfect.

Comment: Did you try the last revision I just posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this looks fun. Anyway, here's [my answer](http://jsbin.com/upuref/50/). I've been watching this for a few days and though I'd chip in too. The following will make sure that the hovering images do not go out of the viewport and in the event that the width of the image is bigger than the available space for display, the display of the image will be resized (You can comment out the code that does this if you don't want it. Just look for the word "resize" in the code).

```
var $document = $(document);
$('.simplehover').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // make sure that element is really an image
    if (! $this.is('img')) return false;

    var isrc = $this[0].src, ibox = null;

    if (! isrc) return false;
    ibox = $('<img />')
            .attr('class', 'simpleimagehover__shidivbox__')
            .css({
                display: 'none',
                zIndex : 99,
                MozBoxShadow: '0 0 1em #000', 
                WebkitBoxShadow: '0 0 1em #000',
                boxShadow: '0 0 1em #000',
                position: 'absolute',
                MozBorderRadius : '10px',
                WebkitBorderRadius : '10px',
                borderRadius : '10px'
            })
            .attr('src', isrc)
            .appendTo(document.body);          

    $this.bind('mouseenter mousemove', function(e) {
        $('.simpleimagehover__shidivbox__').hide();

        var left = e.pageX + 5, 
            top = e.pageY + 5,
            ww = window.innerWidth,
            wh = window.innerHeight,
            w = ibox.width(),
            h = ibox.height(),
            overflowedW = 0,
            overflowedH = 0;

        // calucation to show element avoiding scrollbars as much as possible - not a great method though
        if ((left + w + $document.scrollLeft()) > ww)
        {
            overflowedW = ww - (left + w + $document.scrollLeft());
            if (overflowedW < 0)
            {
               left -= Math.abs(overflowedW);
            }
        }

        // 25 is just a constant I picked arbitrarily to compensate pre-existing scrollbar if the page itself is too long
        left -= 25;
        left = left < $document.scrollLeft() ? $document.scrollLeft() : left;

        // if it's still overflowing because of the size, resize it
        if (left + w > ww)
        {
            overflowedW = left + w - ww;
            ibox.width(w - overflowedW - 25);
        }


        if (top + h > wh + $document.scrollTop())
        {
            overflowedH = top + h - wh - $document.scrollTop();
            if (overflowedH > 0)
            {
                top -= overflowedH;
            }
        }

        top = top < $document.scrollTop() ? $document.scrollTop() : top;
        ibox.css({
            top: top,
            left: left
        });

        ibox.show();
    }); 


    $('.simpleimagehover__shidivbox__').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.simpleimagehover__shidivbox__').hide();
    });

    $document.click(function(e){
        $('.simpleimagehover__shidivbox__').hide();
    });

    $document.mousemove(function(e){
        if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
            return false;
        }

        $('.simpleimagehover__shidivbox__').hide();
    });
});
```

While my solution itself is not perfect, you might find something useful in there that can help you determine the viewport. Also, you might want to think about the performance of the code. Since this is a plugin that you're building, you'll want to make some optimizations before releasing it to public. Basically, just make sure it's not slow.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
html{overflow-x:hidden;}
html{overflow-y:hidden;}
```

All you need to do is add these definitions to your CSS and you're done.

**Update with Resize:** this is the mouseenter code for resizing and repositioning the pictures **BOTH** horizontally and vertically. Now, no matter where the HOVER image shows up, it's resized and positioned to always show in full AND uncut. As far as the scrollbars are concerned, if you show more thumbnails than can fit on the page, you will have scrollbars even before the HOVER images show up.

**FINAL AND WORKING UPDATE:** Because you had focused on the scrollbars being hidden, I think you overlooked the fact that if you put more thumbnails than the viewport can contain, the scrollbars would show up anyway and that therefore, since the user can scroll down the document, when you calculate the position of the hover image, not only do you need to account for the resize but you also to account for the scrollTop position too! **[FINAL JSBIN HERE](http://jsbin.com/upuref/49/edit)**, all pictures are showing RESIZED and in FULL no matter where the scrollTop is and no matter what the viewport size is.

```
$this.mouseenter(function () {

    dv = $('<div />')
          .attr('class', '__shidivbox__')
          .css({
            'display': 'none',
            'z-index': 9999,
            'position': 'absolute',
            'box-shadow': '0 0 1em #000',
            'border-radius': '5px'
          })
          .html('<img alt="" src="' + isrc + '" />')
          .appendTo(document.body);

    var DocuWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var DocuHeight = window.innerHeight;

    var DvImg = dv.find('img');

    var TheImage = new Image();
    TheImage.src = DvImg.attr("src");

    var DivWidth = TheImage.width;
    var DivHeight = TheImage.height;

    if (DivWidth > DocuWidth) {

        var WidthFactor = (DivWidth / DocuWidth) + 0.05;
        DivHeight = parseInt((DivHeight / WidthFactor), 10);
        DivWidth = parseInt((DivWidth / WidthFactor), 10);
    }

    var ThumbHeight = $this.height();
    var ThumbWidth = $this.width();
    var ThumbTop = $this.position().top;
    var ThumbLeft = $this.position().left;

    var SpaceAboveThumb = ThumbTop - $(document).scrollTop();
    var SpaceBelowThumb = DocuHeight - ThumbTop - ThumbHeight + $(document).scrollTop();

    var MaxHeight = Math.max(SpaceAboveThumb, SpaceBelowThumb);

    if (DivHeight > MaxHeight) {

        var HeightFactor = (DivHeight / MaxHeight) + 0.05;
        DivHeight = parseInt((DivHeight / HeightFactor), 10);
        DivWidth = parseInt((DivWidth / HeightFactor), 10);
    }

    var HoverImgLeft = 0;
    var HoverImgTop = 0;

    if (SpaceBelowThumb > SpaceAboveThumb) {
        HoverImgTop = ThumbTop + ThumbHeight;
    } else {
        HoverImgTop = ThumbTop - DivHeight;
    }

    HoverImgTop = (HoverImgTop < 0) ? 0 : HoverImgTop;

    HoverImgLeft = (DocuWidth - DivWidth) / 2;

    dv.find('img').css({
        'width': DivWidth,
        'height': DivHeight,
        'border-radius': '5px'
    });

    dv.css({
        'left': HoverImgLeft,
        'top': HoverImgTop
    });

    dv.fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Comment: It cuts the image by hiding scrollbars I mean if you could have shown that image towards left hand side, scrollbars should not have been visible and no need for `overflow`. So **calculations** are needed not that. I have updated the question.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the picture is larger than the viewport?

Comment: Please see updated answer and my attempt and more explanation of the problem. Your solution with CSS it not answer to this question :(

Comment: I updated the jsbin to do the automatic image resize and positioning: http://jsbin.com/upuref/11/edit Is this closer to what you're looking to do? It's horizontally resized and centered; not sure what you wanted to do with vertical positioning.

Comment: It is cutting/showing half images for second row of images. I hope you get the point now :)

Comment: See the update, it now resizes and repositions both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Edited your jsbin: http://jsbin.com/upuref/27/edit. Removed CSS as I had said. Added more images and there are many cutting up and scrollbars showing up.

Comment: What's your screen resolution?

Comment: If the number of thumbnail images you put on the page exceed the available screen size then of course there are going to be scroll bars no?

Comment: it should not depend on screen resolution. As i had said, this will be a jquery plugin and should work for users with whatever resolution as I cant ask them to change resolution to use my plugin. There are zoom plugins that work nicely without resolution problem

Comment: I have been talking about scrollbars that show up when you HOVER over images

Comment: No, I'm talking about the thumbnails, not the HOVER image: if the number of thumbnails you show on the screen don't all fit because the screen is too small, then will this not mean that scroll bars will appear, since the page doesn't fit?

Comment: Did you try the last revision I just posted?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but @Kemal Fadillah answer is really good, it doesn't size images as well. Thanks again

Comment: But the answer you accepted doesn't show the pictures in full: it cuts part of the pictures out of the screen!! All along, you've been saying that your goal was to make pictures fit on the screen in full!!! Did you check the output of Kemal's answer when a picture is cut?

Comment: No i dont see any pic cutting

Answer (score 1):

You can position the image based on the available width: http://jsbin.com/upuref/19/

This demo takes in account the available space for positioning the image (i.e. the window width minus the image width). Also I've improved the event order, with the popup `div` only starting its fade-in *after* the image has been loaded.

Comment: Thanks but it is still showing vertical scrollbar if you hover over second row of images. The scrollbar can be avoided by showing image upward in this case. You may want to also see my update where I have even done that but as said my algo isn't perfect as I tested it on various sites and sometimes hovered image showed up out of viewport.

Comment: You could reuse the same calculation for the vertical offset, but that approach would require major reorganization of your event handling, as the popup image is almost guaranteed to be positioned under the pointer, which would trigger the `mouseleave` event on the thumbnail and would immediately fade the popup out, as you can see in [an updated demo](http://jsbin.com/upuref/22/). Fixing this goes beyond the scope of your current question.

Comment: My updated demo should give you an idea and events: http://jsbin.com/upuref/14. However the calucation i have used doesn't work on all sites perfectly. You can use any events as long as pop up image shows up on hover and then ability to hide it on mouse away.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question now goes beyond one that can be given a direct answer, and into the realm of building a complex functionality for you. I don't have the time for that and even the bounty isn't much of an incentive. I would build an array of absolutely positioned invisible divs mirroring the size and position your actual images and attach the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` handlers on them; then I would place the popup `div` _under_ that layer of event-capturing `div`s and position the popup `onmousemove` with the same calculation I have already provided.

Answer (score 1):

My answer too ([JSBin DEMO](http://jsbin.com/upuref/41/))

```
$('.simplehover').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        // make sure that element is really an image
        if (! $this.is('img')) return false;

        var isrc = $this[0].src, dv = null;

        if (! isrc) return false;

        $this.mouseenter(function(e){
            // mouse x position
            var initXPos = e.pageX;
            var initYPos = e.pageY+20-$(window).scrollTop();
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            // load original image
            var $img = $('<img/>');
            $img.on('load',function(eload) {
                var widthImage = this.width;
                var heightImage = this.height;
                // set inline style for get sizes after (see problems webkit and cache)
                $(this).css('width',widthImage);
                $(this).css('height',heightImage);
                var ratio = widthImage/heightImage;

                var finalXPos = initXPos+widthImage>windowWidth? windowWidth-widthImage-5 : initXPos;
                var finalYPos = initYPos;

                var img = this;


                // resize image if is bigger than window
                if(finalXPos<0)  {
                    finalXPos = 0;
                    $img.css('width', windowWidth-10);
                    $img.css('height',(windowWidth-10)/ratio);
                }

                // If overflow Y

                if(finalYPos+getSize($img,'height')>windowHeight) {

                    // calculate where is more space (top or bottom?)
                    var showOnTop = (windowHeight-initYPos-10)<windowHeight/2;
                    if(showOnTop) {
                        if(initYPos<getSize($img,'height')) {
                            $img.height(initYPos-30);
                            $img.width(getSize($img,'height')*ratio);
                        }
                        finalYPos = 0;
                        finalXPos = initXPos+getSize($img,'width')>windowWidth? windowWidth-getSize($img,'width')-5 : initXPos;

                    }else {
                        // show on bottom
                        if(windowHeight-initYPos<getSize($img,'height')) {
                            $img.height(windowHeight-initYPos-10);
                            $img.width(getSize($img,'height')*ratio);

                        }
                        finalXPos = initXPos+getSize($img,'width')>windowWidth? windowWidth-getSize($img,'width')-5 : initXPos;
                    }
                }
                dv = $('<div />')
                .attr('class', '__shidivbox__')
                .css({
                    display: 'none',
                    zIndex : 9999,
                    position: 'absolute',
                    MozBorderRadius : '5px',
                    WebkitBorderRadius : '5px',
                    borderRadius : '5px',
                    top: finalYPos+$(window).scrollTop(),
                    left: finalXPos
                }).append($img)
                .appendTo(document.body);           
            dv.fadeIn('fast');
            });
            // load the original image (now is the same, but I think is better optimize it)
            $img.attr("src",$this.attr("src"));

            function getSize($el,widthOrHeight) {
                // horrible but working trick :)
                return +$el.css(widthOrHeight).replace("px","");
            }
        })
        .mouseleave(function(){
            dv.fadeOut('fast');
        });         

    });
```

this script adapt the image to window size and adjust x position if needed.